# macOS Sierra "System" files eating up disk space

Tags: hard-drive, filesystem, macos, storage

macOS Sierra system is using over 200 GB of storage space on my 250 GB hard drive. I've removed Time Machine backups to no avail. How do I free up space? My current usable space being less than 50 GB is getting quite problematic.

**Edit:**

The culprit has been found. Imagemagick is creating tons of temp files for some reason.

[image]

Comment: Adding to the commotion; Space freed up by removing personal files quickly gets eaten up by system

Comment: Please add what you found as an answer and then you can accept it.  This will help others who have a similar problem with this software.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**The Solution**

I used a storage scanning application to see where all the space was going. I used *DaisyDisk*, but Disk *Inventory X* is another option

Turns out ImageMagick image editing library was rampantly creating large files at */private/var/tmp*

[image]